# Comparison between int and argv

Tags: c, int, argv

In my program, I input an `int` value into `argv[1]`. I need to put an `if` statement like this:

```
num = 3;    
if (argv[1] == num)
{
   [...]
}
```

I get a warning: `comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]`
How can compare those two values?

Comment: You need to parse the string into an `int`.

Comment: There is no vector in C. Did you mean array?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `argv`, as passed to `main`, is an array of *strings*.

You can convert a string to an integer with functions like `atoi` or `strtol` (the latter is the preferred alternative). Or you convert the integer to a string, and do a `strcmp`.

Comment: differences between "strtod" and "strtol"? Thank You very much

Comment: @user1409641 `strtol` converts a string to an integer (`long`) type, while `strtod` converts to a floating point (`double`) type.

Answer (score 3):

`num` is an integer, while `argv[1]` is a string that may (or may not) be representing an integer. You can compare only items of the same type, so either compare a string-to-string or an integer-to-integer:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "3") == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if (atoi(argv[i]) == 3) {
    // ...
}
```

The second way will fall apart when you try comparing to zero (`atoi` returns zero to indicate an error).

Answer (score 1):

The command line arguments are strings. You will need to convert these strings first using `atoi` (not suggested) or `strtol`/`strtoul` (better, has error handling) and then use the converted value to compare with whatever integer you want to compare with.

```
char *endptr;
errno = 0;
long int n = strtol(argv[ i ], &endptr, 10);
if (endptr == argv[2])
    ...;  /* no conversion */
else if (*endptr != '\0')
    ...;  /* conversion incomplete */
else if (errno == ERANGE)
    ...;  /* out of `long int''s range */
...
```

Comment: how to use "strtod" function in this case? Than You very much

Comment: @user1409641: `strtod` is for converting strings to floating point numbers. It was a typo. I've fixed the typo. Use one of `strtol` or `strtoul` (the latter is used for `unsigned` integers). Added some code for you to get started.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 3;    
if (atoi(argv[1]) == num)
{
   [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read a number from argv[1] using various methods, then compare with num. (s*scanf)

One that's most specific for you: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtol.html

Or print num into a string and do a strcmp with argv[1] (s*printf)

Comment: how do i convert "num" to a string?

Comment: `int argnum = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); if(num == argnum) {} `

Comment: `char tmp[8]; sprintf(tmp,"%d",num); if(strcmp(argv[1], tmp) == 0) {}`